# Compressed messages are not showing up in eventhub

Tags: c#, compression, gzip, azure-eventhub

I am using GZIP compressor to compress the messages and trying to push the data in to eventhub from my console application. When I push the messages to eventhub it is not throwing any exceptions and at the same time, the data is not showing up. This is the code I wrote to push the data in to eventhub after compressing

```
var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString("");
                var eventData = new EventData(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.Result.Value));
                eventData.Properties.Add("Compression","GZip");
                eventHubClient.SendAsync(eventData);
                eventHubClient.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The difficulties are not related to compressing the message body.  You're not awaiting the completion of the `SendAsync` call before calling `Close`.  This effectively cancels the send because you've closed the network connection that it was using.

To ensure the send is complete before closing, you'll need to adjust your code to something similar to:

```cs
var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString("<< CONNECTION STRING >>");

var eventData = new EventData(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.Result.Value));
eventData.Properties.Add("Compression","GZip");

await eventHubClient.SendAsync(eventData);
eventHubClient.Close();
```

For better performance, I'd also suggest that you consider creating the `EventHubClient` once and treating it as a singletone for the lifetime of your application.